# Retrieving data from Json to input into a dropdown box

Tags: jquery, json

Very much a beginning to HTML and javascript, so please bear with me. As a sort of project, I've been trying to overlay the met office rainfall layer over a google map. I have the maps and all the other layers and I can retrieve the rainfall layer if I manually input it into the code.

Using the JSON file: 
http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/layer/wxobs/all/json/capabilities?key=db801cab-6195-4c7b-8c86-a0ab8fdf1a72

I want to retrieve the 'Time' data from the 'Rainfall' layer. I know this is done by JQUERY but I just cannot get it to work. The below seems the best way I've tried to place the times into a variable. I want to then use these variables to put into a dropdown box.

Any help is appreciated.

***EDITED CODE***

```
$.getJSON('http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/layer/wxobs/all/json/capabilities?    key=db801cab-6195-4c7b-8c86-a0ab8fdf1a72&callback=?', function(data) {
  if(typeof data == "object" && data.post)
  $.each(data.layer, function(index, val) {
  if( val.LayerName == 'Rainfall'){
    var time = val.time,
    rain = val.LayerName;
  }     
document.write(time);

 })
});
```

Comment: unfortunately your api is refusing remote requests with "Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: here is a test http://jsfiddle.net/XX6kx/ open console and you will see the error.

Comment: I've managed to amend the code to get past that error, and also added the error check code for a null value. Now it seems i'm just not able to pull back the required data. I used a document.write just as a test to see if it works. Any ideas? Many thanks